# Why does my ControlTemplate for Grid not work?

Tags: wpf

I want to set the ControlTemplate of grid to look like this:
[image]

Here is the markup:

```xaml
<Grid>
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="0.8*"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></ContentPresenter>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
    <Border Background="Red"></Border>
</Grid>
```

I don't know why the ControlTemplate doesn't work. Is there something wrong with my markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Grid.RowDefinitions` and `Grid.ColumnDefinitions` are no `Dependency properties`, and can't be set by a Style. I guess this is why you used a `ControlTemplate` instead of setting it directly. But the [default Style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/dd334411(v=vs.95)) of the `ControlTemplate` does not show any Borders/Lines, therefore you may want to use a [ContentPresenter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples) (Wrap it around your Grid and not inside of it).

Additionally: To place the Border in the Center of the Grid, you must set the Row and Column, otherwise the Border is spread across the whole Grid. And place it right there where you have your ContentPresenter inside the Controltemplate, not outside of it.

**Edit**

Due to the clarification in the comments i suggest to use a Border which shrinks the Content with a RenderTransform.

Style

```
    <Style x:Name="Shrink80pcBorder" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
        <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.8" ScaleY="0.8"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Usage

```
    <Border Background="Red" Style="{StaticResource Shrink80pcBorder}">
        <Your Item/Content/>
    </Border>
```

Comment: Beaucase there is some many items I need to set it 80% width and height to its parent,so I want to use Controltemplate to make it easier.

Comment: The border which is red that is the item I want to set width and height 80% to its parent.

Comment: So the main goal is to shrink the Content of the Border to 80%, correct?  Do you want to put something inside the 10% Borders or can they be ignored?

Comment: And i forgot to ask: Do you need the dashed lines of the Grid?

Comment: Sorry for just off duty.I don't want to put something inside 10% but just ignore it.What's more,don't need dashed lines,it is I use photoshop to show the 10%,Ah ha.

Comment: Ive updated my Answer to fit your needs. Without the dashed lines its very easy to shrink the Content and you dont need a `Grid` with complex Row/Column Definitions. + Im glad to help, gratitude is always appreciated.

Comment: Unbelieveable!I don't know even has this way to do it!Thank you!

Comment: There are several ways to accomplish things, especially with the Code/Markup possibilities. If this Suggestion solves your Problem, please mark the Answer as accepted Answer.